# Html.BeginForm() Não Submete model, ModelState.IsValid = False

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net

Seguinte estou com o Html.BeginForm() onde o mesmo Submete o model porem qunado vai para o controle a mesma se encontra false o ModelState.IsValid.
Segue Modelo, Controle e BeginForm
Modelo:

```
[Table("TB_Estado")]
public class Estado
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string sigla { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
}
```

Controle [Post]Create

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Estado estado)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Estados.Add(estado);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(estado);
    }
```

View Create

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Estado</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sigla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sigla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.estado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.estado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Veja a imagem que ilustra o problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como Solicitado pelo pessoal a inspeção da Keys e Values de ModelState, ja havia analisado e o mesmo diz que não foi possivel converter a String, sendo que os campos são todos String e simples, o ID é auto incremento. Estou começando agora no ASP .NET MVC e peço desculpa por qualquer Nubisse, rsrsrrsrs.

Mensagem de erro = "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'pedicare.sidigital.com.br.web.Models.Estado' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o objeto `estado` está vindo null... isso significa que não é valido. Não está errado.

Comment: Inspecione o `ModelState`, propriedade `Values`.

Comment: Na mesma imagem que você postou, se você clicar nas setinhas de `> Keys` e `>Values`, ele irá te mostrar exatamente o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Qual é o `@model` da sua *View*?

Comment: Primeira amostra de codigos que coloquei, esse é meu maior problema, não entendoo porque de não reconhecer como String.

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar neste caso.

Comment: Dificil este caso. Procurando outros meios.

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei o problema deste caso.
Verifiquei que na assinatura do método post `Create(Estado estado)` o objeto Estado tem o mesmo nome da variável da classe estado "estado", o que confunde o *ModelBinder*. Nesse caso, trocando o nome da variável interna, o problema foi resolvido.

Depois de solucionado encontrei o post abaixo do Fabio Gantmans, segue abaixo o link.

http://www.aprendadotnet.com.br/Artigo/1094/asp-net-mvc-5-model-binder-null-no-httppost